# Не получается использовать html код по значению переменной в php

Tags: php, html, if

Собственно, хочу показывать ссылку только при steam==false. Однако, задаю steam=true и ссылка всё равно вылазит.
Прошу прощения, если глупый вопрос)

```
<?php if($steam == false) { ?>
<div id="steam_a">
  <a href='https://store.steampowered.com/login' target="_blank">Login throw steam</a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

```
<?php
$steam = true;
require_once('header.php');
?>
```

Comment: то есть код из первого блока находится в файле header.php? а файлы находятся в одной и той же директории?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский именно

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Убрал эту строчку во втором файле:

```
require_once('header.php');
```

Добавил в первый файл перед открытием `<html>` такую строчку (нужно прописать полный путь начиная от папки с проектом):

```
<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/www/games/blocks/steam.php"); ?>
```

Видимо проблема была в том, чтобы первый файл вообще увидел, что функция существует.